# ignore the selected size for featured image

Tags: wordpress

I set a size using the code below :

```
add_image_size( '350x350', 350, 350, false );
```

then in the elementor widget, I selected the featured image and the image size of this size :

[image]

but what is strange to me is that after a while the featured image size is displayed correctly, the selected featured image size is ignored and the original size is displayed.

what is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have anything else changing the size in any other place.

Comment: i only use one size and that is 350, i checked that all the images have this size